# Worklight Hybrid application with a colored background displays a white line at the bottom

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Worklight Hybrid application with a colored background displays a white line at the bottom in IOS 7.1. 
The same problem of https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/ios_7_1_is_around_the_corner?lang=en

I'm using Worklight version 6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 , but it did not fix the problem reported the above.

Comment: it seems that the problem has been corrected in version 6.1.0.1 Font[http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI12337] . Not yet tested. But as soon as possible I'll check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, Worklight 6.1.0.1 fixes the bottom white strip in iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 6.1.0 to 6.1.0.1, and the problem was solved.