# Worklight apps with white bar at the bottom of screen on iOS 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have a number of apps developed with Worklight 6.1 running on iPhone and iPad devices. They worked well with iOS 7.0. However, after the latest upgrade of the iPhone/iPad devices to iOS 7.1, these hybrid applications have a white bar at the bottom of the screen which is about 15-20 pixels in height. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Worklight 6.1 in combination with iOS 7.1, a white line, strip, will appear at the bottom of the app. To remedy this, you must use Worklight Studio **6.1.0.1**, which contains a fix for this specific issue.

See here:

- [Release notes](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/ibm_worklight_6_1_0_1_now_available?lang=en)
- [Changelog](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27041452)

Similar question:

- [Worklight Hybrid application with a colored background displays a white line at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542219/worklight-hybrid-application-with-a-colored-background-displays-a-white-line-at)

Comment: What about fixing that on Worklight 6.0 ?

Comment: This is fixed in all versions of Worklight already - 5.0.6.2, 6.0.0.2, 6.1.0.1.

Comment: I recently installed 6.0.0.2, but the iOS project was created few months ago and already deployed with some modifications. Should I delete the platform and add it again, or there is an easier way to fix that?

Comment: I don't know, it depend son your specific situation. Thoroughly read the technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574

Comment: I have just deleted the platform iOS, and added it again, 
I can see that the white bar is here! Seems that 6.0.0.2 does not fix the issue

Comment: Provide a demo project showing this issue to confirm what you're saying.

Comment: demo available at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31521022/wl/bug_ios7.1/DemoProject.zip and my Worklight version screenshot at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31521022/wl/bug_ios7.1/wl_version.png

Comment: I tested both a new project and your demo project, and in both there is not white strip at the bottom in iOS7.1; my studio version is 6.0.020140427; I suggest that you visit Fix Central and download the latest 6.0.0.2 iFix.